# Vue JS Add Custom HTML attribute to script tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using plausible analytics instead of Google Analytics and need to add their script to the head of the doc. I've built my site using Nuxt JS and have created a custom plugin to add the script but the Vue Meta api only seems to accept predefined attributes to a script tag. I need to add a custom attribute "data-domain" to the script and can't figure out how to.

This is my **~/plugins/plausible.js** file:

```
export default ({ app: { head, router, context } }, inject) => {


 head.scripts.push({
    src: "https://plausible.io/js/plausible.js",
    async: true,
    defer: true,
    "data-domain": "jmcardle.co"
  });
};
```

nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [{
        src: '~plugins/plausible.js',
        mode: 'client'
    }],
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To use an object key of `data-domain`, you'd need to quote it correctly, ie `"data-domain": "example.com"`

Comment: Added that and now getting: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Please update the code in your question to match what you currently have

Comment: @Phil updated :)

Comment: If your `head.scripts` is undefined - then you should first do `head.scripts = [];` before calling `head.scripts.push()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And vue meta does not work?

```
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      script: [
        {
          src:
            'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js',
          supercoolattribute: 'supercool',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
```

[image]

Works well for me

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called [vue-head](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-head) that allows you to manipulate the head-tag in Vue JS.